# Handle Views in routing backbone js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

What is the best way to switch to a different view when user navigates to a different url. In angular there is ng-view that takes care of this and inserts corresponding templates and in ember its all route based.

Is it better to just hide other views elements on routing using css or destroying other views and inserting current view?

**EDIT**

It would be great if someone could give an example how to re-render the view on navigating back to it again and restoring its previous state.

Eg.

if you have a check-box in a view that user can select to add some item to the cart , but in the middle he/she moves to some other url and then comes back, that check-box should be checked.

Comment: I don't have much experience with backbone, but this blog post seems to be what you're looking: http://ianstormtaylor.com/rendering-views-in-backbonejs-isnt-always-simple/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a main content view with subviews and call remove on it, which is responsible for cleaning up any subviews too (calling remove on them first and going up the hierarchy tree). The concept of subviews doesn't come for free with backbone but isn't hard to implement. And finally attach a new content view.

This ensures you can cleanup and the browser is using a consistent amount of resources.

I would abstract this into some kind of layout view which has a content subview and a function like `setContent(view)` which handles the remove of any existing content view and the attach of the new one.

Personally I would have a router with sub routers in modules, e.g. a main router which finds a route starting with "checkout" and passes it over to a sub router in the checkout module which is responsible for attaching a new content view.

In Backbone the implementation is up to you which is both good and bad, depending on how nice you do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Always remove the view as opposed to just hiding it. If you don't remove (and unbind) your views properly, all bindings, handlers and references to models/DOM elements will linger around.

Depending on the size of your app, you can have a module that handles layouts (as suggested by dominic-tobias), or have a method on the router that takes care of this for you. At its most basic, this method (let's call it _switchView) takes a view and holds onto an instance of the currentView. Upon view change, it removes the current view, sets the new view to the current view and then renders it to the DOM.

Something like this:

```
_switchView(view) {
  this.currentView && this.currentView.remove();
  this.currentView = view;
  this.$rootEl.html(view.render().$el);
}
```

Comment: the only reason i like hiding is its easy to go back to the exact state of the app.Say there is a check box that is checked and the user navigates to some other view and comes back to the view... destroying the view will make it really difficult to go back to the previous state of the view.

Comment: I prefer having the model hold on to state and have my views reflect the model. If the model changes, so does the view. And if the model has not changed, the view should look exactly the same.